# Check ListView checkbox items using Autoit

Tags: listview, checkbox, autoit, syslistview32

I am using Autoit to automate Microphone Enhancements in Windows Microphone settings dialog box. I want to check checkbox Items in SysListView32 regardless of them already checked or not. I can toggle by sending space, but that unchecks the item if its already checked. i want to check them in any case. How to do that?

How can i loop through each checkbox item in SysListView32 and check it? All items are checkbox items. I did not created the SysListView32, its in windows sound settings dialog box. Any Solutions?

Comment: Did you try the ControlCommand ...

Comment: Yup, that didn't worked for me! But i did solved the problem finally :)

Comment: @RajaAyaz care to share your solution?